# Why is the movie titled "Her" instead of "She"?

Tags: title, her

Why does the movie *Her* (2013) use the word "Her" instead of "She" as title?

Comment: Because it's about "her" not "she"?...it's the appropriate designation for a native English speaker.

Comment: @Paulie_D That...depends pretty much on what you think the title is saying. Of course it's *about her*. But...the title *isn't* "About Her", it's just "Her" and for a single world without context "She" makes about as much sense as "Her" does (one could even say it makes more sense, being the nominative, which is probably what the question is trying to posit). But of course if you think that's what the title is saying, feel free to flesh that out into an answer.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you feel like it should be *She*?

Comment: @KyleDoyle No, I don't.  I'm working one one of my project items which related to a conceptual analysis based on the semantic of certain movie title, hence the reason I wondered about the titled question.

Answer (score 3):

[A possible explanation](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/feb/13/her-review):

> Theodore falls deeply in love with Samantha, and she with him, but **she is a mystery, a mystery partly signalled by the title: "her" rather than "she", the object of a man's perception and entranced bafflement.**

[Another](https://newrepublic.com/article/116063/spike-jonzes-her-scariest-movie-2013):

> **The title of *Her*, Spike Jonze’s excellent but deceptively dark new film, is less anodyne than it first appears: the antecedent of that pronoun is properly not a *her* but an *it*.** “Her” is Samantha, or rather “Samantha”—a computer/smartphone operating system, voiced by Scarlett Johansson in her signature New York contralto, developed some time in the near future and purchased by Theodore (a finely withdrawn Joaquin Phoenix), who soon falls in love with her.
>
> [...] “It’s not just an OS. It’s a consciousness”—so goes the tagline for OS1, and **note the pronoun choice**.
>
> [...] Instead Jonze skips directly to Theodore booting up the new OS, which, in Johansson’s voice, **identifies herself (I feel manipulated using that word, but *itself* seems impossible)** as Samantha. [...]
>
> [...] As Theodore begins to use the OS nonstop, even *sleeping* with it — **less creepy when that *it* feels like a *her*** — not just his data but his entire life become a form of economic production for an unseen company. [...]
>
> [...] Samantha, or the thing we call Samantha, does not enslave Theodore; but Element Software does, via the deception that such a being as “Samantha” exists, **that *it* is in fact a *her***. [...]

Answer (score 2):

One reason to avoid "She" as a title would be to avoid confusion with the many film adaptations of H. Rider Haggard's *She*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She:_A_History_of_Adventure#Adaptations

Answer (score 2):

"She" is the subjective pronoun, while "her" is the objective pronoun. So the choice of "her" indicates that the title character is the object, rather than the performer, of the action, as Theodore, not Samantha, is the primary viewpoint character.